# Trigger a function when the user scrolls the element into the viewport – Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, viewport

I have written a function which animates a bar chart. Currently this action is being triggered on page load, but I only want it triggered when I get to the element – otherwise the user wont see the animation.
I would like to achieve this through vanilla JavaScript, is it possible?

Here is my mark up:

```
<div class="section">
  section
</div>
<div class="section">
  section
</div>
<div class="section">
  section
</div>
<div class="section">
  section
  <ul class="skills__list">
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>HTML</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="90%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>css</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="80%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>Javascript</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="60%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>UI design</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="70%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>sketch</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="50%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>Photoshop</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="80%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="skills__list-item">
      <div class="bar">
        <span>Illustrator</span>
        <div class="bar__inner" data-percent="90%"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the Scss:

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 400px;
  &:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  &:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #aaa;
  }
  &:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #bbb;
  }
  &:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

.skills__list-item {
  & + .skills__list-item {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

// bar chart styles
.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;

  span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
  }

  &__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transition: width 0.6s linear;

    &::after {
      content: attr(data-percent);
      align-self: center;
      padding-right: 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar__inner');


Array.from(bars).forEach((bar, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const eachBar = bar;
    eachBar.style.width = bar.dataset.percent;
  }, index * 400);
});
```

Here's a working example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/antonymoss/pen/YBLzpj).

Comment: Do you mean *when the user scrolls* the element into view?

Comment: Also, post the relevant code directly here, not just as an external Codepen.

Comment: @AndyG yes that's correct.

Comment: @Amessihel hey, I've added the CSS now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can follow a [very helpful tip](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/) of the website [Gomakethings.com](https://gomakethings.com/).

It shows that you could use the **[`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)** method to achieve your goal:

```
// Get the an HTML element
var element = document.querySelector('<a selector>');

// Get its bounding client rectangle
var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Use it to build a function which checks if the element is in the viewport client by retrieving the bounding box (okay, the code could be improved, it's just a demo):

```
function isInViewport(element) {
    // Get the bounding client rectangle position in the viewport
    var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    // Checking part. Here the code checks if it's *fully* visible
    // Edit this part if you just want a partial visibility
    if (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        console.log('In the viewport! :)');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Not in the viewport. :(');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, add an **event listener** on **`scroll`** event which call the above function:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (isInViewport(theElementToWatch)) {
      // update the element display
    }
}, false);
```

According to the browser compatibility [displayed by the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility), **`getBoundingClientRect()`** is fully supported by Chrome and Firefox (>= 3.5). The provided solution here is fully supported by the most used browsers (it's unknown for some mobile versions).

According to the one provided by [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#search=getBoundingClientRect) website, mobile browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) fully support the method, at least from a given version.

Finally, you could keep in mind a still-experimental solution that aims to replace the use of the method **`getBoundingClientRect()`**, the **Intersection Observer API** (see Tom M's answer). [The MDN related page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) explains why:

> Implementing intersection detection in the past involved event handlers and loops calling methods like `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` to build up the needed information for every element affected. Since all this code runs on the main thread, even one of these can cause performance problems. When a site is loaded with these tests, things can get downright ugly.

Comment: Note the `isInViewport` and `isInViewPort` typo

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) API for this.

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => { 
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry.target);
        // your callback here
    })
}); 

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.skills__list-item'));
```

Mind the [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=intersection) though, it's not supported in IE, Safari and Opera Mini for instance.

[image]

If you want to support IE7+ you can use [the polyfill provided by the W3C](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) though.

**Resources**

- [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)
- [A cool blog post by david walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/intersection-observers)

Comment: Great job, but I would need to support IE-11.

Comment: @AntonyMoss added a link to the IntersectionObserver Polyfill incase you still want to try it

Comment: For some reason, this is running even if element is outside viewport (initial load)

Comment: @Abzoozy i recommend looking at the examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API and building something that fulfills your needs going from there